# Html how do I get this folder

Tags: html, css, directory

I have two folders in my website.
My directory structure like this: 
[image]
In my file inside Cidadao I want to get a file from assets.

I am trying code like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="site/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

but this is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get from inside a folder to one level up, use `..`

This is not confined to HTML though; all computer languages work like that. (Some need the slashes to be the other way around, but the principle is the same throughout.)

Answer (score 0):

you just have the path incorrect.

it should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/site/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">`

Or you could try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">`

Or you could also try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">`

one of those above 3 should work, `/` are important when it comes to filepaths.